# Reading each sheet of excel workbook in separate dataframes and rename the columns by prefixing the sheet names before them

Tags: r

I am trying to read sheets from an excel workbook. There are 10 sheets in that workbook and all have different names.

What I want to do:

1. Read workbook's first sheet's name (suppose the name is "My Sheet
   1")
2. Read the data into a data.frame whose name should be My_Sheet_1
3. Change the column names such as new column should have "My_Sheet_1_" as prefix such that if the name of column in sheet is
   "My Column 1" then in R's data.frame it should be renamed to
   "My_Sheet_1_My_Column_1"... and so forth.

I tried using:

```
read_allsheets_from_excel <- function(filename) {
  sheets   <- excel_sheets(filename)
  x        <- lapply(sheets, function(X) read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
}
# read now
read_allsheets_from_excel("DATA.XLSX")
```

Also tried:

```
My_Column_1 <- read.xlsx("DATA.XLSX", sheetIndex = 1)

colnames(My_Column_1) <- colnames(My_Column_1, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "My_Sheet_1")
```

But none is working. Neither it is a good way to automate across all the 10 different sheets. How can it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. What you need to do is to rename the columns in your loop and to use `assign` to create the variable in the global environment

```
library(readxl)

datasets <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")

read_allsheets_from_excel <- function(filename) {
   sheets <- excel_sheets(filename)
   setNames(lapply(sheets, function(.) {
      tbl <- read_excel(filename, sheet = .)
      names(tbl) <- paste(., names(tbl), sep = "_")
      tbl
   }), sheets)
}

# read now
allSheets <- read_allsheets_from_excel(datasets)

lapply(names(allSheets), function(nam) 
    assign(nam, allSheets[[nam]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
ls()
# [1] "allSheets"                 "chickwts"                 
# [3] "datasets"                  "iris"                     
# [5] "mtcars"                    "quakes"                   
# [7] "read_allsheets_from_excel"
```

Comment: it does not change the col names in the dataframes :(

Comment: What do you mean? `names(mtcars)` gives me
`[1] "mtcars_mpg"  "mtcars_cyl"  "mtcars_disp" "mtcars_hp"   "mtcars_drat"
 [6] "mtcars_wt"   "mtcars_qsec" "mtcars_vs"   "mtcars_am"   "mtcars_gear"
[11] "mtcars_carb"`? Or do you mean to rename the columns in the Excel file? In this case I would anyways use VBA.